# Finding the Four-Velocity vector in the Kerr spacetime between two points?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, kerr-metric

For over a year me and a friend have been working on a Kerr Black Hole renderer. We are close to the finish line and get renders like these;

[image]

[image]

[image]

These renders show aberration of light due to the cameras moment, encapsulated in the four velocity vector $\vec{u}$.To make a long story short, what we take the 3 component vector $\vec{rayDir}$ (Indicating where each pixel of the camera is looking) from its rest frame to the local ZAMO. Then we transform from the ZAMO to the global frame.

At the very core of this transformation is $\vec{u}$. It determines the initial momentum of the camera.

The problem we have is that the camera right now only supports free falling animations. We can give the camera initial momentum along the $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$ arguments and then let it fly in a free fall. But we cannot animate it and maintain the aberration.

Ideally, what we would want to do is have a trajectory defined by a set of points $p_n$ in 3D space. The Camera follows these points and $\vec{u}$ is set such that the momentum the camera has matches the momentum (or change there off) to get from $p_1$ to $p_2$. In other words, a "powered" trajectory.

Getting the camera to move from $p_1$ to $p_2$ is trivial. But we have no idea how you would compute the four velocity vector needed to go between these to points in a given time $t$. We are also not sure how, if at all, this would work in the Ergo Sphere.

[image]

This illustration, perhaps more clearly, shows what we need. For a defined trajectory we need a way to compute $\vec{u}$ between two points. We could imagine the camera is strap to a rocket which exactly "cancels out" the black holes influence.

Because we imagine such a solution inside the Ergo Sphere is impossible (or rather $\vec{u}$ would tend to infinity) it would be ok if anything you guys have only works exclusively outside the ergo sphere.

Right now, $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are pre defined before a render starts and only change if the camera is allowed to free fall. $u_0$ is computed from the others.

Thanks for reading this, and thank you for any help.

EDIT; Just to be 100% clear, the ZAMO stuff above is there to establish that our Camera gains aberration through its momentum. The question itself is about how we can find the momentum (four velocity vector $\vec{u}$ so that in time $t$ the camera will move from $p_1$ to $p_2$.

Another way of imagining it would be, "What four velocity $\vec{u}$ would the camera need to have, starting from $p_1$, to reach $p_2$ in time $t$ if it was in a free fall for this distance ?

Comment: Is this not just the numerical derivative of the trajectory?

Comment: @Javier can you elaborate ?

Comment: Since you are using the ZAMO's frame as the local reference frame, why shouldn't it work inside of the ergosphere? If you use Boyer Lindquist coordinates you can go inside the ergosphere, and in Doran and Null coordinates even behind the horizon, see [here](http://yukterez.net/org/relativistic.raytracer/falling.into.a.kerr.newman.black.hole.html) and in the links therein. Or is your question about the parallel transport, since you are showing a rotation on your rocket?

Comment: @Yukterez the man himself D: The camera can go into the ergo sphere np, the problem we see is with putting the camera "on rails". These "rails" would just be points the camera has to reach each successive frame. So say from theta = 0 to theta = 0.1 in t amount of time. Nothing inherently stops these points from being in the ergosphere, arranged such that the camera is forced to move against the ergo spheres rotation.

Comment: @Yukterez Ran out of words. Yeah the question is about the parallel transport. In essence, if we know the camera has to move from p1 to p2 int time t, what is the momentum u required to do that ?

Comment: You can't have straight rails inside the ergosphere, but you can just let the camera fall freely and calculate the position and 4-velocity for any given t or τ via the geodesic equation, then raytrace the scene from the given position, transform the 4-velocity into the local 3-velocity relative to the ZAMO (Boyer Lindquist) or raindrop (Doran) and apply the corresponding aberration. If you force it to move from point p1 to point p2 in a straight line you can't do that in the ergosphere, but are the rails really what you want or was that because you thought they would make things easier?

Comment: @Yukterez Our renderer supports a free falling camera, putting the camera on rails would be an addition. We are currently writing a Blog about the process and it occurred to use that having the camera be "animatable" with fixed points would be a useful addition and allow for some more interesting renders. This is why i said it is ok if the solution dosnt work inside the ergo sphere. Its just an addition.

Comment: Can we assume that the points are very close together, so that the four-velocity can be approximated as $u^\mu \approx \Delta x^\mu / \Delta\tau$? Or is the question about connecting an arbitrary pair of points with a geodesic?

Comment: @Javier We could make sure points are never further than some maximum distance away from each other using interpolation. So assuming the points are very close might work, it can at the very least be assumed for now yeah

Comment: @Javier as for the 2nd part of your question, the goal is to have a set of points that describe a "Powered trajectory". As in, imagine the Camera is on a rocket and it burns to pass through these points. And we want to find the $\vec{u}$

Comment: But is the camera on a rocket or in free fall? If it's on a rocket, then the four-velocity at a point can be more or less whatever you want since the rocket can maneuver to reach the next point. You would need to better define the conditions in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be very easy or very hard depending on what exactly your goal is.

The simplest case is if you approximate the trajectory of the camera as a series of points that are very close together - essentially, if you have a discrete approximation to the path. The four-velocity is just the derivative of the trajectory, $u^\mu = dx^\mu / d\tau = (dt/d\tau) dx^\mu / dt$. If we have two points $x^\mu_1$ and $x^\mu_2$ that are very close to each other, we can just approximate this with a finite difference as $u^\mu \approx \Delta x^\mu / \Delta \tau$, where $\Delta x^\mu = x^\mu_2 - x^\mu_1$. In practice we don't know $\Delta \tau$, but this is easily fixed: just calculate $v^\mu = \Delta x^\mu / \Delta t$ (where of course $\Delta t = \Delta x^0$), find the norm $|v| = \sqrt{- v_\mu v^\mu}$ and define $u^\mu = v^\mu / |v|$ so that it's normalized.

Now, if the two points are not close, then the question is "What initial condition $u^\mu_1$ should I set at $x^\mu_1$ so that the resulting trajectory passes through $x^\mu_2$?". And here the answer again depends. If the camera is in free fall between these two points, you want to know the initial condition needed for a geodesic to pass through a given point. This is a very hard problem, because as far as I know there's no explicit form for the geodesics in Kerr spacetime, only first integrals. You could try taking a look at these (they're written out in Chandrasekhar's book, among others) and try to figure out what the four-velocity (or four-momentum) should be to make the geodesic pass through the two given points. I don't see a simple way to do this at the moment.

If the camera is on a rocket, though, then the velocity can basically be whatever you want - after all, the camera can just move itself to pass through $x^\mu_2$ later, no matter what its initial velocity. In this case you would have to specify some condition on the trajectory in order to define what four-velocity is the best.